# Adobe Flex Set style for component state

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I have a gradient

```
<s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
   <s:GradientEntry id="gradient1" color="0xFAFAFA"
                    color.over="0xC7C7C7"
                    color.down="0xBBBBBB" />
   <s:GradientEntry id="gradient2" color="0xF0F0F0" 
                    color.over="0xB2B2B2"
                    color.down="0x8B8B8B" />
</s:LinearGradient>
```

and I would like to keep the 3 color values for each gradient in a CSS style sheet.  I dont want to create a style for all GradientEntrys, I want this to be specific to only these two gradients.  I know how to do this for the color property, but how do I set it for the color.over and color.down?

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set specific values for a style property on different states, you can use the : operator like this:

```
#myButton
{
        chromeColor: #eeee00;
}

#myButton:down
{
        chromeColor: #ee00ee;
}
```

This will tell Flex to use a different color on the *down* state of *#myButton*.